# IOT continually connection to PHP through wifi and modbus

Tags: wifi, modbus-tcp

I am now working on PHP part. I know pretty less about IOT so the question might be strange, but I will be appreciate if anyone can give me an example, concept or even a way to learn.

The idea way is to let the PLC device can keep connection with server through wifi and modbus tcp to send and read data. the PLC is the modbus client(master) and PHP is the modbus slave(server). the PLC and PHP are placed in different IP address, which means the connection has to be available in not only LAN but WAN. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with PHP code?

Comment: Maybe not, there already has lost of samples about writing PHP code to make a tcp connection. Just as I said, I don't have much concept about IOT. I need some guides to clear the concept about the relation between PLC wifi and server.

Comment: I'm just asking because it's not really good practice to tag a question with a technology which is not relevant to the actual problem. For example you'd either not tag this as PHP or if you are to tag this as PHP then perhaps some PHP code of what you've tried would help in answering your question. That being said, I don't think PHP is capable of managing the physical network layer and WAN and LAN are just that. TCP/IP are at a level after the physical layer so you need to look for OS based solutions.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you! Sorry for misdirection, I have edited my question now. Yeah I hope someone can tell me the concept about the whole process not just some php code.